# Change the default IdentifierGenerator in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

how may I  change the default IdentifierGenerator in Hibernate.

I know i can specify an IdentifierGenerator for a Table with Annotations/hibernate.cfg.xml, but i dont like to specify it for every single Table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing you need is to configure the identifier generation at sessionfactory level.
This feature is not supported in Hibernate.[sessionFactory Configurations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html), [mapping declarations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-mapping)
You have to specify it for for every table.

Comment: May I use my own Generator by using a basic class for all Hibernate Tabels which has only one Filed: id. This id field would be generated with my strategy.

Comment: yeah sure you can use your own Generator, here is a sample implementation of custom identifier generator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632112/hibernate-session-save-issue check the answer by Will Chesterfield